# Code signing issue with embedded frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign

My iOS enterprise signed app failed to install in device at times. The log from device console shows that the code signing for one of the embedded framework is the issue.

```
<Error>: 0x16e3eb000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke222: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13  
 "Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.joar7U/extracted/Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyAppFramework.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)"   
UserInfo={LibMISErrorNumber=-402620415, LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, SourceFileLine=142, FunctionName=+[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:],   
NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.joar7U/extracted/Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyAppFramework.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)}
```

This issues doesn't come all the time, but when this happens I notice that _codesignature folder inside ipa for the framework contains 4 files. (codeDirectory, codeResources, codeSignature and codeRequirements ). On a normal case I only see CodeResources. I also notice that the variables inside info.plist file is not expanded.

I tried to validate via the code sign tool using  "codesign -vvv" I get the code sign is valid. It tried clean before build but the issue occurs after that too.

Any help or pointer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in my case was empty "`PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER`". Even though `CFBUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` is set, xcodebuild expects it(PBI) too in case of embedded frameworks.

But it is really strange that only few of the builds are corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the bundle identifier for any embedded framework definitely seems to do the trick. I'm not even sure it matters what you change it to as long as it has it set.